# How can I re-use PHP code across different pages?

Tags: php

I would like to re-use some PHP classes and functions that I have written to display tables.

Right now, I am using XYZ PHP Code to display tables on multiple pages. In each snippet, I am defining a table class and related functions. I believe it would be much cleaner if this table class was defined only once.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: are you aware of `functions.php`, and PHP includes?

Comment: Put files wherever you would like and include or require them from functions.php which is the main file in your theme that WordPress automatically includes on every script execution. All of WordPress and all other proper php code uses includes extensively to avoid declaring classes or functions twice.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for something similar to PHPs require or include function.

In WordPress we can use `get_template_part( 'example-folder/template' );` to get `template.php` from the `example-folder`.

You should also look into the get_template_part function to see the capabilities. If you're wanting to include outside variables into these, you can use PHP globals.

Comment: You should not use get_template_part for all includes. Only use it for template files inside of the templates folder in your theme and even in that case i would suggest you may as well just use a regular old include.

Comment: template-parts folder **